# Iterating through multiple ranges to create a new sheet and update data

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

I'm trying to create a new sheet labeled with a different identifier from a range and also have two cells from other ranges included on each update. I can get the new sheets to create with a different label from a range, and have the first cell in the second range (xRg2) added to each subsequent sheet, but haven't been successful at iterating through the second range. I know I need another loop somewhere but my last nest created way too many sheet. See example below

```
Sub Add()
 Dim xRg As Excel.Range
 Dim xRg2 As Excel.Range
 Dim wSh As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim wBk As Excel.Workbook
 Dim wSh2 As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim wSh3 As Excel.Worksheet
 Set wSh = ActiveSheet
 Set wBk = ActiveWorkbook
 Set wSh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List")
 Set wSh3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template")
 Set xRg2 = wSh2.Range("G66:G88")
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 For Each xRg In wSh2.Range("B66:B88")
   With wBk
     wSh3.Copy after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
     On Error Resume Next
     wSh.Name = xRg.Value
     wSh.Cells(33,7) = xRg2.Value
     If Err.Number = 1004 Then
      Debug.Print xRg.Value & "already used as a sheet name"
     End If
     On Error GoTo 0
   End With
  Next xRg
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True End Sub
```

So, to summarize, the goal here is to input the ranges into the code each time and have each new sheet include the first values from each range, then the second sheet the second values from each range, and so on until the xRg is at the end of it's list. I know there's only two ranges down here but the total will be 3. Also apologies on the poor variable discipline...

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you are missing a quote... `wSh2.Range("B66:B88)`

Comment: `Set wSh = ActiveSheet` you qualified the other sheets. Do it with this one too. Edit: also `wSh.Cells(33,7) = xRg2.Value` this should be `xRg`?

Comment: hello can I ask what qualifying the sheet would do ? Also, that's correct the value updated in the sheet is from a different range. I'm changing the sheet names to the values of xRg and the content updates would come from xRg2

Comment: okay.. not sure how that's helpful. the idea behind not qualifying the sheet as I did with the others is I don't want it to become static. in each iteration the activeSheet is the one that's been created...

Comment: `wSh.Cells(33,7) = xRg2.Value` should maybe be `wSh.Cells(33,7) = xRg.EntireRow.Columns("G").Value`

Comment: @findwindow - this `Set wSh = ActiveSheet` seems OK to me?  There's no problem with using `ActiveSheet` if that's really what you want, and stating that explicitly in your code clarifies the intent.  The more risky thing is the *implicit* use of `ActiveSheet` (ie. not using any worksheet qualifier with `Range` / `Cells`.  However that's not the issue here - `wSh` always refers to the *same sheet* - that line needs to be inside the loop after the `Copy` line

Comment: @TimWilliams that line seems unnecessary to me if OP meant to manipulate each activesheet? Hard to tell considering I am unsure the goal.

Comment: Agree and maybe I mis-interpreted your comment so apologies in that case...

Comment: No need to apologize. OPs code is really confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (sorry do not like all those x... variable names)

```vb
Sub Add()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsList As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsList = wb.Worksheets("List")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each c In wsList.Range("B66:B88").Cells
        
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Copy after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)  '<< get the just-created sheet copy
        On Error Resume Next
        ws.Name = c.Value
        ws.Cells(33, 7) = c.EntireRow.Columns("G").Value
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
            Debug.Print "'" & c.Value & "' already used as a sheet name"
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        
    Next c
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```